# Отрезать последнее предложение Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Дана строка:
*'В Москве с 1 июля на 4,6% поднялись цены на услуги ЖКХ. Соответствующее распоряжение в прошлом году...'*

Необходимо отрезать последнее предложение '*Соответствующее распоряжение в прошлом году...'*, нужно учесть что перед *последним* предложением могут стоять знаки обозначающие конец предложения `[.!?]`. И если, например, нет обозначающих знаков конца перед последним предложением то не отрезать. Например такое предложение: *'Коронавирус, победили...'*

Пробовала так: `r'((?![.!?] ).)*[.!?]$` - отрезает, но и отрезает пример с коронавирусом тоже.

Мысли были такие: идти с конца строки циклом, который бы искал знак который бы обозначал конец строки `[.!?]`, если находилось то отрезать нужный кусок, т.е последнее предложение. Но я не понимаю  как реализовать.
Примерно так пыталась, но тут возникает проблема, если делать вот так:

```
x = 'будет призывать своих сторонников бананов приходить на участки лишь в последний день. По мнению булочки, так поступить нужно для того, чтобы...'

f = x[:-3]
for i in reversed(f):
    if i in ['?','!','.']:
        result = re.sub(r'((?![.!?] ).)*[.!?]$', r'', x)
        print(result)    
    else:
        print(x)
```

Цикл выдаст и результаты которые мне подходят, и результаты которые нет.

Comment: А если там будет текст в кавычках и внутри него знаки? )  Вообще задача непростая на самом деле. Хотя если все варианты известны, то проще

Comment: Да, я думала об этом, а еще есть такие как например Инициалы, С.Куропаточкин, и т.д)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдёт вот такое выражение: `(?<=[^.!?][.!?])[^.!?]+[.!?]+$'`

```
import re

for x in ('будет призывать своих сторонников бананов приходить на участки лишь в последний день. По мнению булочки, так поступить нужно для того, чтобы...',
          'В Москве с 1 июля на 4,6% поднялись цены на услуги ЖКХ. Соответствующее распоряжение в прошлом году...',
          'Коронавирус, победили...',
          'Один. Два? Три! Четыре!'):
    print(re.sub(r'(?<=[^.!?][.!?])[^.!?]+[.!?]+$', '', x))
```

Результат:

```
будет призывать своих сторонников бананов приходить на участки лишь в последний день.
В Москве с 1 июля на 4,6% поднялись цены на услуги ЖКХ.
Коронавирус, победили...
Один. Два? Три!
```

Comment: В целом это подходящая регулярка, спасибо)